# PayPal Checkout Button not redirecting to my custom Payment Page

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal's integrated credit card payment on my site, which works great. The customer has the option of staying on my website and paying by credit card or they may choose to "pay with PayPal" by clicking either the "Check out with PayPal" button or the "Check out with BillMeLater" button. The issue I am having, is for some reason, when customers click these buttons, it directs them to my generic PayPal payment page and not the customized PayPal payment page I have created and designated as primary. Depending on the browser, sometimes customers are directed to the correct page. But it's random.
Here is mu URL if you want to test out what I am attempting to explain.
http://www.cozeeclothing.com/index.php

Thank You,
John